# Trajectories on the surface of a sphere

Tags: 3d, algebraic-curves, spheres, parametrization

[This link](http://curiosamathematica.tumblr.com/post/104148292523/some-interesting-3d-lissajous-curves-on-a-sphere) shows some 3D Lissajous curves and [this one](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalSpiral.html) shows a spherical spiral on the surface of a sphere. I was wondering where I can find a source listing several other possibilities of trajectories on the surface of a sphere (ideally including the corresponding parametric equations).

Does anyone know such a source?

Comment: In case it helps, if $x$, $y$, and $z$ are functions of one variable that do not vanish simultaneously, then$$c(t) = \frac{(x(t), y(t), z(t))}{\sqrt{x(t)^{2} + y(t)^{2} + z(t)^{2}}}$$is a curve on the unit sphere.

Comment: You could use spherical coordinates, angles $\theta$ and $\varphi$: $$\begin{cases}x = \sin(\theta)cos(\varphi) \\ y = \sin(\theta)\sin(\varphi) \\ z = \cos(\theta)\end{cases}$$with$$\theta = \frac{\pi}{2} \sin( C_0 t)$$and$$\varphi = \pi \sin( C_1 + C_2 t )$$ where $t$ is your curve parameter, and $C_0$, $C_1$, and $C_2$ are the constants that define the curve. (This is not an answer, because I'm too lazy to look up the rules for $C_0$, $C_1$, and $C_2$ for the result to be a Lissajous curve.)